# casting a type to another type in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm a beginner in OOP, just have a question on casting, let's say we have:

```
interface Animal
{
   string speak();
}

class Dog : Animal
{
   public string speak()
   {
       return "wan-wan";
   }
}

class Cat : Animal
{
   public string speak()
   {
     return "miao";
   }

   public void catchMouseS()
   {
      ...
   }
}

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
     Animal generic= new Dog();
     Cat cutie = (Cat)generic;   
    }
}
```

so you can see that I can type a dog to a cat, the compiler is OK with that, shouldn't the compiler be smart enough to throw an error, because it will encounter error on run time for sure when the 'cutie' calls the catchMouses method since cutie is actually a dog which doesn't have catchMouses method?

Comment: In this particular case it could, but that's a toy example, not particularly relevant for real-world usage, so it doesn't bother checking for it

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: This doesn't throw an error at compile time but as @MichaelRandall says this will throw a run-time exception. If you ran your code you'd see that very quickly. See [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wwYDwt) fiddle to see this in action. As far as the compiler is concerned, you're casting an `Animal` to a `Cat` which is possible. If you change `generic` to be `Dog` you'll see a compiler error.

Comment: The exception will happen when you try to perform the cast, not when you try to invoke the `catchMouseS`. FYI the plural of mouse is mice, not mices.

Comment: @Michael Randall I did explicitly said there is no compilation error, of course there will be runtime error when you run the program, but why not the compiler be smart enough to detect the error?

Answer (score 0):

The case you described is called [downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) and is considered a bad code for the exact reason you have mentioned. It is allowed at compile time, and crashes (or misbehaves) in runtime (or not).

You could also catch [InvalidCastException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidcastexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) and do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the way polymorphism and interfaces work in .Net.

The compiler can statically analyse the *Type* of the *Reference*, but it doesn't dig into the run-time *Type* of the *object* in memory. It knows enough to know those 2 types implement the same contract and can make an *Explicit Conversion*, and it's good with that for good reasons.

Now, to you and me it's obvious `Dog` is not a `Cat`, we can see it in a handful of code, but the compiler doesn't try and figure out that type of problem at compile time. You could imagine if you had a million lines of code it would have to check billions (if not trillions) of path-ways to work-out if what you are doing is correct... All it knows at compile time is the *Type* at casting is valid (not what you try to do with it), and a conversion is possible.

So, to save time on what is really an enormous problem with lots of degrees of freedom, (the compiler) does a basic *Static Check* to see if there is a possible conversion, and allows you to make a mess of it, however it still does the run-time check.

Here is another way to hoodwink the compiler

```
class Dog
{
}

class Cat
{
}

public static void Main()
{
    Dog d = new Dog();
    var a = (object)d;
    Cat cutie = (Cat)a;
}
```

Both are *reference types*, both can be converted to *object*, and both conversion are seemingly possible, so it thinks you know what you are doing at compile time, obviously though the run-time checks fail.